# Нет и нету — в чем разница?

Tags: стилистика, лексика

Хотелось бы узнать, в чем разница между словами "нет" и "нету" (оба в значении "нечто отсутствует"). Или "нету" — чисто разговорное?

Comment: А еще говорили "*нетути*"...

Comment: to @grumant.  А у Исаковского "Лучше нету того цветУ, Когда яблоня цветет."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**НЕТ** - в функц. сказ. кого-чего. Нормативная речь. Н-р: У меня *нет* яблок.
**НЕТУ** - в функц. сказ. кого-чего. Разговорная речь. Н-р: У меня *нету* яблок.

Answer (score 7):

Да, "нету" - разговорный вариант "нет".

Answer (score 1):

to [[@grumant](/users/1349/grumant)](/users/1349/grumant)  Ну, просто не понял, что это Вы там изменили...

```
   > Лучше нету того ЦВЕТУ,
     Когда яблоня цветет,
     Лучше нету той минуты,
     Когда МИЛАЯ ПРИДЕТ.
```

Ведь именно так у Исаковского М.В.(Хотя к делу и не относится.Просто уточняю.).

Comment: В доступных мне источниках - везде "милый мой придет".

А нет, пардон. Нашел и "женский" вариант.
http://rupoem.ru/isakovskij/all.aspx#luchshe-netu-togo

А вообще очень многие "народные" песни существуют в "мужском" и "женском" вариантах. Под исполнителя.

Comment: http://rupoem.ru/isakovskij/luchshe-netu-togo.aspx

Я так понимаю, сначала были стихи. А в песне, конечно, - под исполнителя.

Comment: http://love-you.net.ua/vne-rubrik/isakovskij-mihail--luchshe-netu-togo-tsvetu-kogda-jablonja-tsvetet.html

И еще есть поверьте. только там, где речь идет о стихах.